# How remove duplicates from sql list?

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate

```
<property name="xxDescribtionNumbers" formula="(
                select nvl(listagg(A.NUMBER, ', ') within group (order by A.NUMBER),' ') 
                from  ENTER E
                left outer join ADRESS A on A.ID = E.ADRESS_ID
                where E.BUILDING_ID = ID
                )" />
```

This will make a list of numbers but can contains duplicities, but I don't want any duplicities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by removing the values in a subquery:

```
select coalesce(listagg(va.CISLO, ', ') within group (order by va.CISLO), ' ') 
from (select distinct a.cislo
      from VCHOD V left join
           ADRESA A
           on A.ID = V.ADRESA_ID
      where V.BUDOVA_ID = ID
     ) va;
```

Comment: When I use it it's not works, because I can't know A.CISLO in first row, "%s: invalid identifier"